# Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK and Filtering - How to construct a request to filter on two different dates?

Tags: c#, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am coding against the `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` and I am working on proofing out the ability to filter an `IDriveSearchCollectionPage` object between two different dates.

My request looks like:

`await graphServiceClient.Drives["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"].Search(searchQuery).Request().Filter(...).GetAsync();`

I noticed that there is a `.Filter()` method that lives on `IDriveSearchRequest` but it only accepts one argument of type `string`. I took a look at the Microsoft Docs, [Filtering Docs](https://dev.onedrive.com/odata/filtering.htm).

After reading the docs, I am still having trouble constructing a `.Filter()` which takes in a date and compares it with a `DateTime.Now` object.

Here is my current request:

`await graphServiceClient.Drives["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"]
                    .Search(searchQuery)
                    .Request()
                    .Filter($"02-15-2017 lt {DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")}")
                    .GetAsync();`

When I execute this request I get `Bad Request` error. Can anyone give me a hand with a .`Filter()` where I am just trying to compare two dates?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug is to get a capture of the request and response, sanitize it by removing PII and access token, and then share it here. Without seeing that, I'm making guesses.

Issues I see:

1. I don't know for sure whether you can perform a search and filter in
   the same request. I'm guessing no. Try using just one at a time.
2. If you want to use the filter, it needs a property to target. Specify the property you want to target instead of 02-15-2017 in the filter.

Comment: I have been doing some digging. I read a note on the OneDrive Api docs that said something along the lines of: "filtering support only *name* and *url* properties". Url: https://dev.onedrive.com/odata/filtering.htm

Based on this note - are we only able to filter on `Name` and `Url` or can we also do `createdDateTime` for OneDrive for Business?

Comment: I'd start with what that document states. With that said, I suggest that you try creating a createdDateTime filter in case the service and docs are out of sync. If it doesn't work at this time, I suggest that you vote and comment on the following feature request: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16755322-add-filter-support-for-onedrive-for-business